# У нас есть две команды: «Лига святых » и «Кошечье ухо» / «Лига Святых» и «Кошечье Ухо»

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать названия команд?

> У нас есть две команды: «Лига Святых» и «Кошечьи Герои».

> У нас есть две команды: «Лига святых» и «Кошечьи герои».

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150538/discussion-on-question-by-----------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            ДИАЛОГ
            – Пусть уберет уши, тогда отвечу.  
            – Убрал. Мур-мур.
```

**ВВЕДЕНИЕ В ТЕМУ**

Я уже говорила о том, что в теме прописных букв очень много **частных** регламентаций, но  нет **систематизации** материала. Но все же можно условно разделить все темы на **три группы**:

(1) **Все слова** в составном имени пишутся с прописной буквы (индивидуальные имена и официальные названия государств, высших должностей).

(2) **Несколько слов** могут писаться с прописной буквы.

(3) **Только первое слово** пишется с прописной буквы (обычно названия предприятий, учреждений).

Наиболее проблемной является  **вторая группа,** где приходится выбирать прописную букву в середине имени. Там с прописной буквы, кроме первого слова,  пишутся **условные (не реальные)** названия и слова особой **значимости.**

**Приведем примеры:**  *улица Кузнецкий мост, площадь Красные Ворота, город Белая Церковь, Северный Ледовитый океан, созвездие Большой Медведицы, Высокое Возрождение, Великая Отечественная война, орден Трудового Красного Знамени, День Победы и т.д.* К этой же группе относятся названия **спортивных** команд, для которых условные названия **характерны.**

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

*У нас есть две команды: **«Лига Святых» и «Кошечьи Герои»**.*

В  названиях команд с прописной буквы пишется **первое** слово, а также **второе** слово, так как оно имеет **условное** значение. Значение слов ***святой*** и ***герой*** не является реальным, так как  не соответствует словарю. О каких святых и героях может идти речь, если это название спортивной команды.

**Или соответствует?** В нашей реальности соответствия нет, но может быть **у котов** свои святые, а **герои** из их команды имеют удостоверения на это звание.

Поэтому делаем вывод еще раз: тему пусть обсуждают сами коты, а иначе можно получить **неправильное решение** орфограммы.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  К ТЕМЕ ОТ 28.12.2023 по комментариям**

Интересна ситуация **с "Сибирскми Снайперами"**. Возможно, сам клуб может называться "Сибирские снайперы", но в турнирной таблице записано: Сибирские Снайперы.

Почему же так? Здесь интересна словарная статья: **СНАЙПЕР**, -а; м. [англ. sniper]. 1. Стрелок, владеющий искусством меткой стрельбы, маскировки и наблюдения. Снайперы укрылись на крышах домов. Стрелять не хуже снайперов. **2. Проф**. Спортсмен, без промаха забивающий гол в ворота, корзину противника.

**Значение указано, но с пометкой проф.**

https://snipers.hcsibir.ru/

Вот как важна **словарная статья** при выборе названия команды. Все учитывается, но нет **произвольного выбора прописной буквы**  по своему желанию.

Answer (score 2):

Вот есть "Крылья Советов" - Советы знамо кто, Крылья, потому что клуб от авиапрома.

> Профсоюз рабочих авиапромышленности выбрал для своего ДСО название «Крылья Советов».

Есть "Горняк-УГМК" - Уральская горно-металлургическая компания, то есть.

"Крылья Советов":

А есть "Сибирские Снайперы" - клуб "Сибирь", основной спонсор завод "Сибирский Антрацит"(антрацит - каменный уголь, если что), молодёжка, почему "Снайперы" не ясно, просто так, логики нет. Ну и они сами не решили как их писать, на сайте написано "Сибирские снайперы", в строке ввода, а в сетке пишут "Сибирские Снайперы".

А есть "Омские ястребы" - тут вроде по правилам русского языка, но без такого пафоса как у снайперов.

Так что нет какого-то четкого правила, зависит от желания того, кто клуб называет, и не считается орфографической ошибкой.

Так как название "Кошачьих Ушей" ты и выдумал, то как правильно писать, знаешь только ты, вот такой ребус!

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150537/discussion-on-answer-by-----------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.